# Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 Error before game even starts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-forge

When I try to run Minecraft with Forge already installed, one of two things happens. Either my game actually loads and it comes up as a complete black screen not showing my game at all but it says it is running, or it comes up with this error:

```
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.10.0.1151 for Minecraft 1.7.10 loading
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_05, running on Windows 7:amd64:6.1, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
    [15:00:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
    [15:00:56] [main/INFO] [FML]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft Forge.  Certificate fingerprint e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557
    [15:00:56] [main/ERROR] [FML]: The minecraft jar file:/C:/Users/Reisinger/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1151/1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1151.jar!/net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class appears to be corrupt! There has been CRITICAL TAMPERING WITH MINECRAFT, it is highly unlikely minecraft will work! STOP NOW, get a clean copy and try again!
    [15:00:56] [main/ERROR] [FML]: For your safety, FML will not launch minecraft. You will need to fetch a clean version of the minecraft jar file
    [15:00:56] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Technical information: The class net.minecraft.client.ClientBrandRetriever should have been associated with the minecraft jar file, and should have returned us a valid, intact minecraft jar location. This did not work. Either you have modified the minecraft jar file (if so run the forge installer again), or you are using a base editing jar that is changing this class (and likely others too). If you REALLY want to run minecraft in this configuration, add the flag -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true to the 'JVM settings' in your launcher profile.
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

[image: This is the image of what it looks like when I have not done anything, just installed forge and ran it]

Comment: `The minecraft jar file:/C:/Users/Reisinger/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1151/1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1151.jar!/net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class appears to be corrupt! There has been CRITICAL TAMPERING WITH MINECRAFT, it is highly unlikely minecraft will work! STOP NOW, get a clean copy and try again!` - From your error log.  Looks like you missed something.  How did you install your mods?  Did you follow the directions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft

Comment: This for some reason appears to not have been closed in 2016. That doesn't change the fact that @JimJones was entirely correct as to its off-topicness and thus I am flagging it for closure again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft

Answer (score 1):

I had a very, very similar problem to this and fixed it using the Delete & Reinstall approach.

- Rename: ..\AppData\Roaming.minecraft to ..\AppData\Roaming.minecraft_broken
- Re-install Java
- Re-run minecraft.exe to reinstall Minecraft
- Install the latest version of Forge

Re-run Minecraft and shiver with glee as it runs without error!

I'd definitely recommend taking a copy of ..\AppData\Roaming.minecraft when you have a stable build of Minecraft, as things usually start to fail when you combine mods.  You can then just replace the files in the .minecraft folder with the backed up version when things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simple:

```
[15:00:52] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_05, running on Windows 7:amd64:6.1, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
```

Try following these steps to fix the issue:

**Tip 1:** Try down grading Java to Java 7. This is just a fail safe. Forge definitely works with Java 7

**Tip 2:** Make sure you have launched Minecraft without Forge before trying with Forge. Sometimes this can fix issues with Forge and Minecraft compatibility.

**Tip 3:** Make sure you are running the correct version of Forge.

There is no need to uninstall Minecraft and re-install.

---

**How To Install Forge for Minecraft 1.7.10**

Here is a quick tutorial video I made on [installing Forge for Minecraft 1.7.10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYhW1hEx0xY)

1. Download Forge for 1.7.10 from [here](http://files.minecraftforge.net/)
2. Activate the installer and select "client"
3. Open Minecraft launcher and select "New Profile" (bottom left)
4. Name the profile something like "Forge 1.7.10" and select Forge 1.7.10 from the drop down a little further done the profile making page.
5. Save the profile. Select your new profile and hit "Play"

Enjoy playing modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur at 2 different sources.

1. You overwritten some classes in the jar files.
2. The forge installation is corrupt.

In the first case, i could guess you installed mods through dumping the mod contents into the jar file. If the mod installation requires you to do so, follow their instructions carefully to avoid this error. Either that or you are using outdated/mismatched version of the mod to the minecraft client.

In the second case, a clean installation can be done to resolve this issue. To do so, go to your start menu and search for %appdata%. Select the roaming folder and backup the .minecraft folder. Delete it afterwards and reinstall minecraft from scratch. Also get a fresh copy of MCF and install that.

Answer (score 0):

-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true

Add that to the JVM arguments. You encountered a rare bug that I got as well and this fixed it for me.